# How to reference .NET assemblies using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, assemblies

I am a C# .NET developer/architect and understand that it uses objects (.NET objects) and not just streams/text.

I would like to be able to use PowerShell to call methods on my .NET (C# library) assembies.

How do I reference an assembly in PowerShell and use the assembly?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Take a look at the blog post *[Load a Custom DLL from PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell/)*:

Take, for example, a simple math library. It has a static Sum method, and an instance Product method:

```
namespace MyMathLib
{
    public class Methods
    {
        public Methods()
        {
        }

        public static int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int Product(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile and run in PowerShell:

```
> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\temp\MyMathLib.dll")
> [MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(10, 2)

> $mathInstance = new-object MyMathLib.Methods
> $mathInstance.Product(10, 2)
```

Comment: The link is loading here. I will update my post and copy the relevant part from the it.

Comment: Thanks for the text. :) I know now why I couldn't find the answer when I was searching. I'll try it and let you know how I go. :)

Comment: You can also use the `Add-Type` cmdlet.

Comment: @Johannes Rossel - How do I use the Add-Type cmdlet? From the get-help command it appears to be for dynamic assemblies?

Comment: @Russell: `add-type -path .\foo.dll`. You can also use it to directly compile code.

Comment: @Johannes, you should add it as a new answer. I'll vote it up ;) I think if possible standard PowerShell means should be used and pure .NET only if needed.

Comment: @stej: Same here. Although `Add-Type` didn't exist prior to v2, if I'm not mistaken, so it deserves a mention, although no separate answer in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Johannes, Darin is basically right. His solution will work. However, if somebody else will come here (e.g. from google), he will see his answer and will not read through the comments. That's why I think there should be another answer with `Add-Type`.

Comment: @stej: You can give it, then. You need more rep than me in any case ;-)

Comment: hi guys, thanks the add-type is what I am looking for. :) It would be good to put it in a separate question as Add-type is a nicer solution (more built-into powershell), albeit for V2.0 and above.

Comment: 404 on the link at the start of your post.

Comment: Does this not work for .NET Standard dll's? I'm getting this error when I run the `Add-Type -Path "C\some.dll"`     `Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: This example looks allot like Lee Holmes - https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell/.

Answer (score 71):

With PowerShell 2.0, you can use the built in Cmdlet Add-Type.

You would just need to specify the path to the dll.

```
Add-Type -Path foo.dll
```

Also, you can use inline C# or VB.NET with Add-Type. The @" syntax is a HERE string.

```
C:\PS>$source = @"
    public class BasicTest
    {
        public static int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }

        public int Multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a * b);
        }
    }
    "@

    C:\PS> Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source

    C:\PS> [BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)

    C:\PS> $basicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest 
    C:\PS> $basicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)
```

Comment: A couple options for that PowerShell in Visual Studio: http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/ PowerShell Plus: IDE  http://powershellplus.com/

Comment: The latest ISE has intellisense.

Comment: Add-Type : Cannot add type. The ".EXE" extension is not supported.

Comment: just press tab for autocomplete, and get used to doing `|gm` a ton. no need for an IDE.

Comment: I worked around 'The ".EXE" extension is not supported' by renaming it to .DLL :P

Comment: How does this work when you have a class with a bunch of dependencies?