# Calling C# function from VBScript function in Web UI

Tags: c#, vbscript

I need to call or at least pass parameters into C# function from within VBScript function (or suitable workaround) on Microsoft Azure Website Hosting i.e.:

```
Function VBScriptFnc(param_1, param_2, param_3)

  Dim flag;

  flag = 1

    'call the C# function or somehow pass parameters into C# function'
    csharpFunction(param_1, param_2, param_3)


  VBScriptFnc = flag

End Function
```

Comment: I think you'll need to compile the C# code into an assembly, and then call the method through the .dll, similar to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79314/How-to-call-a-NET-DLL-from-a-VBScript

Comment: ..yes, except that is not so simple (registering DLL) when you are on the basic Azure hosting level. Is there any easier option ? I could always POST the values into the C# script but that seems atrocious.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'C# script'. C# is a managed language that has to be compiled and built in order to use it. I must be missing something...

Comment: I see. The situation is as follows. There is one VBScript website and one C# website (both belong to the same project). The files for both applications are in the same root. I would like to call the C# function specified in one of the .aspx file from the VBScript function specified in the .asp file.

Comment: BTW posting the parameter values from VBS into the C# script is not a good idea. Also Azure limits the size of POST / GET values to approx 1600 chars.

Answer (score 5):

VBScript has 5 windows into the .NET world:

1. By doing HTTP POST/GET to a .NET handler of some kind (such as a .aspx, HTTP handler, MVC or WebAPI controller).
2. By writing data to a file or a database for a .NET process to pick up.
3. By [exposing a .NET assembly (class library) as a COM object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and adding the appropriate entries in the Windows Registry (either manually or using command utilities) so it can be called directly from VBScript. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79314/How-to-call-a-NET-DLL-from-a-VBScript).
4. Making an executable file with .NET that is run directly from VBScript.
5. Using [PowerShell to call into a .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell) and using [VBScript to call PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/18/how-to-use-vbscript-to-run-a-powershell-script.aspx).

The most straightforward option on a website is to use a GET or POST because you will steer clear of the mine fields of ACL and COM registration, but if you must go down another road I would say that PowerShell is your best bet, followed by COM interop as a third choice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your assembly as COM visible by setting the COMVisibleAttribute to true (either at assembly level or at class level if you want to expose only a single type).

Next you register it with:

```
regasm /codebase MyAssembly.dll
```

and finally call it from VBScript:

```
dim myObj
Set myObj = CreateObject("MyNamespace.MyObject")
```

This Answer Originally Posted By [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769332/how-to-call-c-sharp-dll-function-from-vbscript).