# Azure Functions: PowerShell Script Interacting with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-functions

I'm playing around with Azure Functions, specifically a PowerShell script function. I'm wondering how I can use a script that is reaching out to SharePoint Online.

To run against SharePoint Online I would normally use the "SharePoint Online Management Shell" which is a version of PowerShell that pre-loads the SharePoint Online library so that I can use methods like Get-SPOSite, etc.

How can I include this library in my Azure Function PowerShell script so that I can use these functions? I'm assuming I need to load the library at the top of my script, but how do I load the library?

I've uploaded the DLL into my function and am trying to use:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll')
```

But this doesn't appear to work. I think my issue is that I don't know the absolute path to my uploaded file. This is what I see on the left hand pane:

[image]

But I don't know what the path of these files are.

Any ideas? Documentation is frustratingly slim with the Azure Functions at the minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path to your Azure Functions directory is

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\<YourFunctionName>
```

In the most recent Azure Functions release (version 0.3) we support loading DLLs on your behalf.  You will need to create a folder named **modules** and upload the DLL into that folder.  In fact, you are now be able to upload *script (.psm1), binary (.dll) and manifest (.psd1)* modules into the **modules** folder and they will be automatically loaded before executing the script.

Let's use the sample [MyMathLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell) assembly as a reference.

Suppose you have a Function named **RunSimplePowerShell**, and have uploaded the custom library named **MyMathLib.dll** into the folder as follows,

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\RunSimplePowerShell\modules\MyMathLib.dll
```

Then, your PowerShell script named run.ps1 that resides in

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\RunSimplePowerShell\run.ps1
```

could be written as follows,

```
[MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(5, 2)

$calculatorInstance= New-Object MyMathLib.Methods
$calculatorInstance.Product(5,2)
```

With Azure Functions release 0.3, you can now skip the line

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\home\site\wwwroot\RunSimplePowerShell\MyMathLib.dll")
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, somewhat.

To find the absolute path of your files you can do so by accessing the console in Azure Functions. To get to the console requires a bit of clicking about. From inside your Azure Function:

> Function app settings -> Advanced Settings -> Go to App Service
>   Settings -> Tools -> Console

You'll see the directory name in the command prompt. You can then use:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("<directory>\MyLibraryNameHere.dll")
```

To pull in your assembly.