# How can I use powershell to call the method in the dll?

Tags: powershell

I need to use Powershell ISE to run the method that is in the dll, but it always show this error :

> Unable to find type [ExportTestResultNamespace.ExportTestResultClass].
>   Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded. At
>   C:\selenium\TestInPowerShell_Net.ps1:36 char:1
>   + [ExportTestResultNamespace.ExportTestResultClass]::WriteAndRead()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ExportTestResul...TestResultClass:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Here is my powershell code :

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('c:\users\brian\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NunitTestLibrary\NunitTestLibrary\bin\Debug\NunitTestLibrary.dll') |Out-Null

$obj_ETC = [ExportTestResultNamespace.ExportTestResultClass]::Create()

$obj_ETC.WriteAndRead()
```

I really don't know what is wrong, can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference .NET assemblies using PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell)

Comment: Are you sure that's the actual namespace and class names? Is `ExportTestResultClass` public?