# tfs 2017 custom task developed with c#

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to develop custom task in tfs 2017 with c# code or only with powershell or nodejs.In xaml builds I can develop my custom activity with c#.But As I see in new tfs we can only develop scripts based plugins

> public class MyCustomActivity : CodeActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom activity in C# and package it in a PowerShell task. [Just use PowerShell to call into the .NET assembly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell) Having some kind of static launcher class/method helps. You'd only need a very thin layer of PowerShell to extract the variables.

The old XAML activities are no longer supported though, you'd have to roll your own.