# Use a .Net wrapper with powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

Is it possible to use powershell to access the functionality of a third party .Net wrapper, given that powershell can leverage .Net classes? The wrapper is available on GitHub and I have downloaded the source files. It has a number of cs files amongst others.

It is also packaged in Nuget but I do not wish to have Visual Studio installed. I am not a software developer. I would just like to be able to call from powershell the features that the wrapper might expose.

Comment: You need a compiled assembly, and then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081491/369

Comment: You could use [http://scriptcs.net/](http://scriptcs.net/) and reference the compiled assembly you want.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the standalone nuget.exe and used it to 'install' the .Net wrapper as a dll file. Then I could use Add-Type to work with it. Thanks for the helpful comments which got me looking in the right direction.