# Loading C# DLL with powershell, [System.Type]::GetType returns null

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a simple DotNet DLL like this

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
           Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C calc"); 
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to load this DLL with powershell

```
$Path      = "c:\\test\\ClassLibrary1.dll";
$Namespace = "ClassLibrary1";
$ClassName = "Class1";
$Method    = "Test";
$Arguments = $null

$Full_Path       = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($Path);
$AssemblyName    = [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($Full_Path)
$Full_Class_Name = "$Namespace.$ClassName"
$Type_Name       = "$Full_Class_Name, $($AssemblyName.FullName)"
$Type            = [System.Type]::GetType($Type_Name)

$MethodInfo = $Type.GetMethod($Method)
$MethodInfo.Invoke($null, $Arguments)
```

It does not work, because `[System.Type]::GetType($Type_Name)` returned `$null`

Any ideas?

Comment: You are not loading assembly. `[System.Type]::GetType` does not load assembly unless it is in GAC or assembly search path.

Comment: You may need to use `LoadFile` as per this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use **[`Add-Type -Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type)** to **load your assembly**.
- After loading, to get a reference to that assembly's `[ClassLibrary1.Class1]` type as a `[Type]` instance (to use for reflection) via a *string variable*, simply **cast to `[Type]`**.

The following corrected and annotated version of your code demonstrates the approach:

```
# Compile the C# source code to assembly .\ClassLibrary1.dll
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    namespace ClassLibrary1
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            public static void Test()
            {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C calc"); 
            }
        }
    }
'@ -OutputAssembly .\ClassLibrary1.dll  


# Define the path to the assembly. Do NOT use "\\" as the path separator.
# PowerShell doesn't use "\" as the escape character.
$Path      = ".\ClassLibrary1.dll" 
$Namespace = "ClassLibrary1"
$ClassName = "Class1"
$Method    = "Test"
$Arguments = $null

# Load the assembly by its filesystem path, using the Add-Type cmdlet.
# Use of relative paths works.
Add-Type -Path $Path

$Full_Class_Name = "$Namespace.$ClassName"

# To get type [ClassLibrary1.Class1] by its full name as a string,
# simply cast to [type]
$Type            = [type] $Full_Class_Name

$MethodInfo = $Type.GetMethod($Method)
$MethodInfo.Invoke($null, $Arguments)
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

As [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) points out, [`[System.Type]::GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) can only find a given type if:

- its assembly is already loaded
- its assembly can be located via standard assembly resolution, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies), which involves many complicated rules, the only two of which likely apply to your scenario is if you're trying to reference a *built-in* type from the `mscorlib` assembly, or an assembly located in the **GAC** (Global Assembly Cache).

  - By definition, only *strongly-named* assemblies - those signed with a private key matching the public key mentioned in the assembly's full name - can be placed in the GAC.

While you could have called `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($Full_Path)` first in order to load the assembly via its filesystem path, after which `[System.Type]::GetType($Type_Name)` would have succeeded, it is ultimately simpler - and more PowerShell-idiomatic - to use `Add-Type -Path` to load the assembly (which has the added advantage of not requiring a full (absolute) file path), and, once loaded, to use `[Type]` with just the *type's* full name (no reference to the assembly needed anymore).