# Calling .NET method with optional parameter by name in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a .NET class with number of optional parameters, say:

```csharp
void Method(int one, int two, int three = 0, int four = 0, int five = 0);
```

Is there a way to call the method from PowerShell, passing a value to the parameter `five`, without listing parameters `three` and `four`?

In C#, I can do:

```csharp
instance.Method(1, 2, five: 5);
```

Is there a similar syntax is PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell has no native syntax for named optional parameters, so we'll need a bit of reflection magic to make this work.

Basically you'll need to count the corresponding parameter index of the named parameters and then pass an array with `[type]::Missing` in place of the optional parameters you want to omit to [`MethodInfo.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke):

```
$method = $instance.GetType().GetMethod("Method") # assuming Method has no additional overloads
$params = @(1, 2, [type]::Missing, [type]::Missing, 5)
$method.Invoke($instance, $params)
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, this is possible. Posweshell is built on top of .Net. you can create an object of .Net class by calling constructor in Poweshell  Here is an article on how to use .Net in powershell.

https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/11/04/net-members-in-powershell.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you include the part of the article that is relevant to the question into your answer? I actually cannot see how it's related.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell check this